# Why do I get authentication error when trying to access PayPal Sandbox (ref REST API app)?

Tags: paypal, webforms, paypal-sandbox

**As requested by Preston PHX, I uploaded a full copy of my
code to Dropbox:**

**[My test ASP.NET Web App](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4uclfs2lexv4v42/AAAjoZIN5cEMV1mu0cYi24zKa?dl=0)**

**I hope this helps someone to identify what I may have done wrong
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@**

I am trying to use the sample code at https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/tree/develop/Samples to make contact with the Sandbox but it doesn't work for me. In order to find out why, I ran my code in Visual Studio under Localhost in debugging mode, using several breakpoints.

This line of code in my test page ...

```
var createOrderResponse = CreateOrderSample.CreateOrder(true).Result;
```

... displayed the following error:

- Inner Exception 2:
- HttpException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"**Client Authentication failed**"}

However, it was the environment function in PayPalClient.cs (modified to use my PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID and PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET) that appears to have generated the error:

```
        public static PayPalEnvironment environment()
    {
        return new SandboxEnvironment(
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID") != null ?
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"):"<<PAYPAL-CLIENT-ID>>",
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET") != null ?
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"):"<<PAYPAL-CLIENT-SECRET>>");
    }
```

I very carefully copied my PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID and PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET from the REST API app I created via the PayPal Developer Dashboard. Apart from that, the GitHub sample code has not been modified. I could see no requirement in the GitHub code to specify a Sandbox URL and assume that this is provided by the PayPalCheckoutSdk via the use of "return new **SandboxEnvironment**()".

It's not obvious to me why my attempt to connect to this Sandbox account is failing the authentication process. What might I be doing wrong? Is it anything to do with my use of Localhost?

***EDIT on 1 Nov 2021 in response to Preston PHX***

Creating a new Sandbox Client ID and Secret made no difference. Prompted by another forum post I read some time ago, I also tried using ngrok (for the first time) to open http port 80 to facilitate PayPal testing via Localhost, but the connection to the Sandbox still failed authentication.

*Sandbox Client ID:* AZcb8XrqhJEUO7lS_JtKSe3sdNDLESmo3ekhupDKTL1J9vQCKVOzacCjO3PBQwSfngYkLGa-qS7EUrGV

*Secret:*

EBEcuPewHdzCB8p0qE1Yszjk2eMyFCstzkL0Diz2WC5IQREsu6cDHr7yFG9a-GDIyljb-KRb2DA6Hoey

I installed curl (plus Bash and Git) on my Windows 10 PC and ran the curl command specified on the [get-an-access-token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/get-an-access-token/) page. I couldn't find a way to post the result here in an easily readable form so I put it in a Word doc and uploaded that to Dropbox.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/knia3y2ighfzxpa/Result%20of%20PayPal%20curl%20command.docx?dl=0

**Edit on 2 Nov 2021**

As requested by Preston PHX, I have uploaded a copy of the ASP.NET Web App I have been using for my tests to Dropbox.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4uclfs2lexv4v42/AAAjoZIN5cEMV1mu0cYi24zKa?dl=0

I've only uploaded the project folder, as I'm guessing that it is unnecessary to upload my Solution files.

Comment: The curl command worked (a word document--really?), so it's not a credential or general network issue, but specific to your code/environment

Comment: Can you please clarify if it is possible to connect to the PayPal REST API via Localhost. The code I'm using is not mine. It's the PayPal sample code from GitHub. What aspect of my environment might be causing a problem?

Comment: @PrestonPHX - I forgot to add your tag when I made my previous comment.

Comment: That question doesn't make sense, a web server on localhost has nothing to do with whether or not that server can connect to API endpoints

Comment: Any number of things about your code and environment could be causing a problem, including typos. You'll need to post a complete, runnable sample if you want anyone to be able to look into it.

Comment: @PrestonPHX - I've followed your suggestion. My complete ASP.NET Web App has been uploaded to Dropbox and my question has been edited to add the required link

Comment: @PrestonPHX - Is there any chance of you checking out the Web App I have uploaded to Dropbox? It would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a new **sandbox** client ID and secret in [the developer dashboard](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).  Test with the new client ID and secret.

If issues persist,

1. Update your question with both the new sandbox client ID, and the new sandbox secret.
2. Update your question with a sample [curl command to get an access token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/), showing the entire command and the entire response in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question as requested.